# Install Tokenizer in Docker Image

Tags: docker, pip, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I need to install `tokenizers==0.12.1` in my docker image. I have it listed in a `requirement.txt` file and have these in Docerfile:

```
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
RUN export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but I get this error:

```
#0 59.54 Failed to build tokenizers
#0 59.54 ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I can install `tokenizer` in a new conda environment but not in docker image.

I have already tried to install rust in the docker file.

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/1231#issuecomment-982762459) might be useful.

Comment: @Ro.oT No. The linked issue is about PHP, the question is about Python and `pip`.